# C# : There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqldatareader

```
        String sql = "SELECT * from mybrknElements; ";
        String sql2 = "";
        String sWord = "" ;
        String sNum = "" ;
        int nWords = 0;
        cnn.Close();
        cnn.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn);
        cnn2.Close();
        cnn2.Open();

        SqlDataReader drb;
        drb = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (drb.Read())
        {
            sNum = drb["ID"].ToString();
            sWord = drb["Element"].ToString();
            MessageBox.Show("OUTER loooop sNum = " + sNum + " sWord = " + sWord);


            sql2 = "SELECT * from mybrknElements2; ";
            String sWord2 = "" ;
            String sNum2 = "";
            SqlCommand command22 = new SqlCommand(sql2, cnn2);

            SqlDataReader drcc;
            drcc = command22.ExecuteReader(); //ERROR comes up after this line 


            while (drcc.Read())
            {
                sNum2 = drcc["ID"].ToString();
                sWord2 = drcc["Element"].ToString();
                if (Equals(sWord2,sWord2))
                {

                    nWords = nWords + 1;
                    MessageBox.Show("sNum2 = " + sNum2 + " sWord2 = " + sWord2);
                }
            }



            //---check occurances--------------


        }
```

Above is my code : I have used 2 SqlDataReaders ,one within other
I get the error at the end of the while loop
: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first

Can someone please help?
Thank you.

Comment: Not related to the error, but do you mean to have `if (Equals(sWord2,sWord2))`? I think you'd want `if (Equals(sWord1,sWord2))`

Comment: At the same time you can only open 1 DataReader

Comment: You can't have more then one open datareader on a single connection.

Answer (score 1):

You should stop reusing your command and connection objects, and dispose of them properly once they have been used. There is no advantage to reusing the objects (.NET will reusing open sockets to the database through connection pooling anyway, even for difference connection objects), and it only causes issues like this.

So without reusing objects, and disposing of the ones you correctly your code might end up something like:

```
string sql = "SELECT ID, Element FROM mybrknElements; ";
string sql2 = "SELECT ID, Element FROM mybrknElements2;";
int nWords = 0;
string connectionString = "Your Connection String";

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql1, connection))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        string sWord = reader.GetString(0);
        string sNum = reader.GetString(1);

        using (var connection2 = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (var command2 = new SqlCommand(sql2, connection2))
        {
            connection2.Open();
            using (var reader2 = command2.ExecuteReader())
            {
                string sWord2 = reader2.GetString(0);
                string sNum2 = reader2.GetString(1);

                if (Equals(sWord1,sWord2))
                {
                    nWords++;
                }
            }
        }           
    }
}
```

*N.B. In each data reader you only use two columns, so I have added these columns to the select list in each SQL statement so that you are not unnecessarily retrieving data that will never be used.*

The whole loop strikes me as pointless and inefficient though, assuming the whole purpose is to get `nWords` with the correct number, you can do this all in SQL:

```
    SELECT  nWords = COUNT(*)
    FROM    mybrknElements AS e
            INNER JOIN mybrknElements AS e2
                ON e2.ID = e.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
        SqlDataReader drb;
        drb = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (drb.Read())
        {
            sNum = drb["ID"].ToString();
            sWord = drb["Element"].ToString();
            MessageBox.Show("OUTER loooop sNum = " + sNum + " sWord = " + sWord);


            sql2 = "SELECT * from mybrknElements2; ";
            String sWord2 = "" ;
            String sNum2 = "";
            SqlCommand command22 = new SqlCommand(sql2, cnn2);

            SqlDataReader drcc;
            drcc = command22.ExecuteReader(); //ERROR comes up after this line 

          drb.Close();

            while (drcc.Read())
            {
                sNum2 = drcc["ID"].ToString();
                sWord2 = drcc["Element"].ToString();
                if (Equals(sWord2,sWord2))
                {

                    nWords = nWords + 1;
                    MessageBox.Show("sNum2 = " + sNum2 + " sWord2 = " +   sWord2);
                 }
               }
            drcc.Close();
          }
```